# UITableView with dynamic prototypes content and multi sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, interface-builder

In xCode 6.1.1 interface builder, when i choose UITableView content of the type "dynamic prototypes" I cant select to have more than one section anymore, any clue how to have table with multi sections and dynamic prototypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to do it inside the interface builder but I have solved it by choosing the "dynamic prototypes" for the UITableView content and then in the UITableViewController added this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return N // number of required sections
}
```

Now I can get my prototype cells while I have multi sections:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as UITableViewCell
```

Hope this will help someone else too.